# How to insert laravel blade table element with one-liner?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to simplify the laravel blade code, so I think about the way to insert table element with one-liner.

This is what I want to achieve.（These codes don't work the way I expect them to. These two '@include' display same element.）

In the util/insert.blade.php

```
@section('insert')
    <tr>
        <th>
            {{$th}}
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name={{$name}} value="{{ $val }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
@show
```

In the main.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
  @include('util.insert', ['th' => 'th1', 'name' => 'name1', 'val' => 'val1'])
  @include('util.insert', ['th' => 'th2', 'name' => 'name2', 'val' => 'val2'])
</table>
```

Do you have good suggestion?

Comment: Why not use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use blade components to achieve that. Instruction on how to use it can be found in the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components
That way you would be able to create a component for the table header, table row, and so on. However I am not sure that I would agree that it would simplify the blade code, but that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop for data

In the `main.blade.php`

```
<table class="table">
  @include('util.insert', ['data' => [
    ['th' => 'th1', 'name' => 'name1', 'val' => 'val1'],
    ['th' => 'th2', 'name' => 'name2', 'val' => 'val2'],
  ]])
</table>
```

In the `util/insert.blade.php`

```
@section('insert')
  @foreach($data as $row)
    <tr>
      <th>
        {{$row['th']}}
      </th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="{{$row['name']}}" value="{{ $row['val'] }}">
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach;
@show
```